# Android listener for window transition not working properly

Tags: android, transition

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am trying to listen window transition through `Transition.TransitionListener().` But it is not giving callback to my listener methods. I tried this in following way:

```
inside oncreate call registerTransitionListener()


private void registerTransitionListener() {
    mEnterTransitionListener = new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
            Logger.print("inside transition start");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            Logger.print("inside transition end");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
            Logger.print("inside transition cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
            Logger.print("inside transition pause");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {
            Logger.print("inside transition resume");
        }
    };
    getWindow().getEnterTransition().addListener(mEnterTransitionListener);
}
```

but it is not printing any logs inside any transition methods. also my device android version is 5.0.2. Need to know how it works? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: NO. My window or activity not having any such kind of flag.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getEnterTransition()